# IE 8 iframe border

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, internet-explorer-8

There is a border showing on an `iframe` and I can't get rid of it.

IE 6 and 7 work as intended with a little JavaScript:

```js
function test(){
    var iframe = document.getElementById('frame2');
    iframe.contentWindow.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#a31d1d";
    iframe.contentWindow.document.body.style.border = "#a31d1d";
    iframe.contentWindow.document.body.style.outlineColor = "#a31d1d";
}
```

But the border remains visible in IE 8.

Comment: StackOverflow has a great preview area below the text area where you enter your question. Use that preview to fix formatting next time before you post.

Answer (score 94):

Add following attributes to iframe tag:

```
marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0"
```

Comment: I tried using jQuery to add these in pragmatically but IE8 seems to just ignore them; after wasting too much time trying to hide a border (what a trivial task huh?) I went with the hard-coded attributes to force this for IE8. "why is IE so rubbish!?" is my favourite phrase today - and yes I am cross browser testing :-D. Hehe. Thanks for figuring this out!

Comment: FYI: Unfortunately adding a frameborder attribute inline in document will make the document to never validate for HTML 5. But there seem to be no other way around this issue.

Comment: frameborder="0" removed the border from the iframe on ie8

Comment: Yeah that makes sense... add three html attributes that I have never used before in my life. Thanks!

Comment: Still a black line is there in IE8

Comment: @ChristopherLightfoot — This was exactly it for me. I was trying to set the attributes with jQuery, but they need to be hard-coded inline attributes of the iframe on initial load for IE to understand them.

Comment: I wish IE10 and below just disappeared from the face of this planet.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem with iframes created dynamically, and it turned out that setting border properties **AFTER** adding the iframe to the document has **NO** effect:

The following code shows a 3d border:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
iframe.src = "http:www.stackoverflow.com";
//Iframe added BEFORE setting border properties.
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.frameBorder = "no";
```

But this actually removes it:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
iframe.src = "http:www.stackoverflow.com";
iframe.frameBorder = "no";
//Iframe added AFTER setting border properties.
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Hope that this would help solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried loads of variations on this idea and ended up using something along these lines. Thought I'd share it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   url = 'http://www.dollypower.com';
   title = 'Dolly Power';
   width = '660';
   height = '430';
    document.write('<iframe src='+url+' title='+title+' width='+width+' height='+height+' frameborder=0></iframe>');
 </script>
```

Then I used noscript tags to enter an alternative for non-JS users, i.e:

```
<noscript><p><a href="http://www.dollypower.com" target="_blank">Please click here for Dolly Power</a></p></noscript>
```

I tested it in IE8 and it's all cool for me and it also validates.

Hope this might help someone out there!

Answer (score 1):

Success!

Try this. It will find any iframe elements and remove their borders in IE and other browsers (though you can just set a style of "border : none;" in non-IE browsers instead of using JavaScript). AND it will work even if used AFTER the iframe is generated and in place in the document (e.g. iframes that are added in plain HTML and not JavaScript)!

This appears to work because IE creates the border, not on the iframe element as you'd expect, but on the CONTENT of the iframe--after the iframe is created in the BOM. ($@&*#@!!! IE!!!)

Note: The IE part will only work (of course) if the parent window and iframe are from the SAME origin (same domain, port, protocol etc.). Otherwise the script will get "access denied" errors in the IE error console. If that happens, your only option is to set it before it is generated, as others have noted, or use the non-standard frameBorder="0" attribute. (or just let IE look fugly--my current favorite option ;) )

Took me MANY hours of working to the point of despair to figure this out...

Enjoy. :)

```
// =========================================================================
// Remove borders on iFrames

if (window.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe"))
   {
      var iFrameElements = window.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
      for (var i = 0; i < iFrameElements.length; i++)
         {
            iFrameElements[i].frameBorder="0";   //  For other browsers.
            iFrameElements[i].setAttribute("frameBorder", "0");   //  For other browsers (just a backup for the above).
            iFrameElements[i].contentWindow.document.body.style.border="none";   //  For IE.
         }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample HTML to go with the sample JS would be helpful =)

Try using IE8's Developer Tools (press F12 on the page you have problems with) to isolate what styles are being applied to the iframe.  You can also play with the styles there, to cut down your iteration time.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that this may be IE not respecting border settings in the css, <strike>whereas the traditional setting of the attribute `BORDER=0` on the iframe element may work. Worth a test, at least.</strike>

Edit: It looks like what does fix the problem is setting frameborder='0' on the iframe element. That worked for me, at least.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to validate you could do this with javascript. I found the perfect answer when I had this problem a few months ago [here](http://www.christersvensson.com/html-tool/iframe.htm)

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
 iframe.src = "banner_728x90.gif";
 iframe.width = "728";
 iframe.height = "90";
 iframe.frameBorder = "0";
 iframe.scrolling = "no";
 document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

f you want to load another page seamless in the iframe you can do this if you copy and paste this code into the head of your page. I found it on a site with free scripts. The performance is good in most cases

```
function getDocHeight(doc) {
    doc = doc || document;
    var body = doc.body, html = doc.documentElement;
    var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
    return height;
}
function setIframeHeight(id) {
    var ifrm = document.getElementById(id);
    var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: ifrm.contentWindow.document;
    ifrm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    ifrm.style.height = "10px"; // reset to minimal height in case going from longer to shorter doc
    ifrm.style.height = getDocHeight( doc ) + 10 + "px";
    ifrm.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

You then give your iframe an id and call the script on load. This is how.

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
 iframe.setAttribute('id', "ifrm1");
 iframe.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.hekcmviw.com/'); // change the URL
 iframe.setAttribute('width', '100%');
 iframe.setAttribute('height', '10');
 iframe.setAttribute('frameBorder', '0');
 iframe.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
 iframe.setAttribute('onload' ,"setIframeHeight(this.id)");
 document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```