# IE frameBorder alternative

Tags: html, css, iframe, internet-explorer-8, w3c-validation

For this line of code:

```
<iframe width="600" height="400" frameBorder="0" src="http://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>​
```

I got this error: (validator.w3.org : XHTML 1.0 Transitional)

```
there is no attribute "frameBorder"
```

I'm using `frameBorder` because IE8 creates some kind of border on iframes. On latest Chrome/Firefox it's fine.

**Is there any other, W3C valid, way to remove border form `iframe` on IE8 ?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE 8 iframe border problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625835/ie-8-iframe-border-problem)

Answer (score 5):

Simply use CSS:

```
<iframe width="600" height="400" style="border:none;" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

p.s. I assume you used stackoverflow in your iFrame tag as an example? Because the site doesn't allow being i-Framed it seems...

Answer (score -1):

Since W3C isn't excecuting Javascript, you could add the attribute later on with Javascript.

Example using jQuery:

```
$('iframe').attr("frameBorder", 0);
```

Comment: Hacking around the test doesn't make it valid.

Answer (score -2):

**All attributes in xhtml are in lowercase.** Try this:

```
<iframe width="600" height="400" frameborder="0" src="http://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>​
```

Comment: `frameborder` isn’t allowed by the validator either.