# Issue with fixed positioned Iframe on IE

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a iframe like this: (this frame appears on left of screen at all time)

```
<iframe src="frame/index.html" class="left"></iframe>
```

and the CSS

```
.left
{
position: fixed;
top: 25%;
left: 1em;  
width:200px;
height:200px;
overflow:hidden;
margin-right:10px;
border-style:none;
}
```

It works perfect in all web-kit browser, but on IE it appears on top(and middle) with border and abnormal height.

I tried messing up with lot of positioning but couldnot get it right.
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance

Cheers!

Comment: Which version of IE are you talking about?

Comment: All of them actually. I tried on IE7, IE8 and IE9!

Comment: IE is known to disregard CSS rules and even JS when rendering `<iframe>` elements - [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65034/remove-border-from-iframe) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625835/ie-8-iframe-border).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding:

```
frameBorder="0";
scrolling="no";
position:absolute;
allowtransparency="true";
```

worked!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this fiddle works on my IE9 (9.0.8112.164).  The positioning looks consistent across browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/5sbXG/2/

I did change the iframe tag from your example to get rid of the scroll bars (IE seems to ignore overflow:hidden on iframes).

```
<iframe src="http://www.rockpapershotgun.com" class="left" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

Does it look wrong from your end?